# Django error deploying to heroku requirements

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my a django app to heroku. I have a virtual environment(of course). I have the procfile, setup.py and runtime.txt set up correctly. It runs perfectly on a local development server, but when I push to heroku it gives some kind of error with the requirements file.

This is the third traceback after pushing to heroku. I changed the procfile the first two times and then it only gave errors with the procfile. Now that the procfile errors are gone I have some kind of error with this.

Traceback:

```
    Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 309 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Uninstalling stale dependencies
remote: Invalid requirement: 'There was a problem loading the given requirements files.'
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 77, in
 __init__
remote:     req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.p
y", line 3036, in parse
remote:     req, = parse_requirements(s)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.p
y", line 2980, in parse_requirements
remote:     "version spec")
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.p
y", line 2945, in scan_list
remote:     raise RequirementParseError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
remote: pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Expected version spec in There was a problem loading the given
requirements files. at  was a problem loading the given requirements files.
remote:
remote: You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
remote: You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web, worker
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 60.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v6
remote:        https://calm-caverns-85777.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/calm-caverns-85777.git
   b1b06b0..d6b1a95  master -> master
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn blog.wsgi
worker: python worker.py
```

requirements.txt:

```
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.9.7
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-markdown-deux==1.0.5
django-pagedown==0.1.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
markdown2==2.3.1
Pillow==3.2.0
whitenoise==3.2
```

runtime.txt:

```
python-3.5.1
```

I can install the dependancies locally from the requirements.txt file and the other thing is when I try to update pip it says it is already up to date. My runtime environment is set to python 3.5.1. The app crashes when it is deployed and I am assuming it is because of the traceback errors. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If you deploy again does the same thing happen?

Comment: Yes it happens again.

Comment: Stupid question: `requirements.txt` under source control?

Comment: Yes @Two-BitAlchemist

Comment: Can you `heroku run bash` just to check it's there, not corrupted, etc?

Answer (score 6):

How was the requirements.txt file created? Is it possible it is corrupted or not plain text or has non-printable characters in it?

I recommend deleting requirements.txt and generating it cleanly based on pip freeze.

If you are using Windows Powershell the [encoding issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3479) could be affecting you. The suggested solution is:

```
pip freeze | Out-File -Encoding ASCII requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, unfortunately I cannot vote for it, hopefully someone else does!